# How do i schedule cron in wordpress for each second?

Tags: cron, wp-cron

I want to schedule a cron job in Wp3.5.1 to sending email to those customer whose appointment is pending.

here some code am trying:

**For the testing am scheduling corn for each second to insert row in table.**

```
// insert row every second
add_action('wp', 'my_activation');
function my_activation() {
    if ( !wp_next_scheduled( 'my_event' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'my_event');
    }
}

add_action('my_event', 'do_this_event');
function do_this_event() {
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO `wordpress-testing`.`wp_test` (`id`, `text`) VALUES (NULL, 'b');");
}

wp_get_schedules('my_event');

//custom recurrence
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'cron_add_every_sec' );
function cron_add_every_sec( $schedules ) {
    $schedules['hourly'] = array(
        'interval' => 1,
        'display' => __( 'Do Secondly' )
    );
    return $schedules;
}
```

May am going wrong  to do this. So please help me through.

**Is cron run automatically after activation once OR its need to recurring visit after scheduled time past?**

Comment: cron running at every second is going to massively slow down your site on shared hosting, and at the same time be extremely unreliable ( you'd need a visitor a second or more for it to work ) and if your cron task takes longer than a second to execute, the next one might not happen

Comment: This is only for testing on local-host to achieve the working behind 'wp_schedule_event()' and recurrence customization. Not for the live site i know its not make sense.

Answer (score 6):

I do not think it is useful to have a cron running every second, but the function itself is quite simple.

You add a filter to the `cron_schedules`:

```
function f711_add_seconds( $schedules ) {
    $schedules['everysecond'] = array(
        'interval' => 1,
        'display' => __('Every Second')
    );
    return $schedules;
}
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'f711_add_seconds' );
```

You can now use `everysecond` in your `wp_schedule_event` instead of the `hourly`.

Note that the Cron is not executed every second, if nothing happens on your site, but it will be limited to max. one execution per second. Cron sets a value in your `options`-table for a timestamp when the function should be executed the next time. Then Cron checks if the time is in the future or in the past, and if it is in the past, the function is executed. The Cron runs automatically at this point but needs to be set again. So be sure to include the

```
if ( !wp_next_sceduled('my_event') ) { /* scheduling code */ }
```

in your code.

For further information on how Cron works visit the [Codex Page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_cron/).

You should not overwrite the `hourly` as you did, as some functions may use this schedule. Please be aware that some Plugins may clear your Cronschedule, if they are not coded properly (had a Caching Plugin like that once).

Comment: Thanks for great knowledge. Thatz means i needs to hit site in every second to run scheduled cron.

`wp_schedule_event( time(), 'everysecond', 'my_hourly_event');`

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what that means :) If you really depend on a Script being executed every second (I can't think of a case where this is necessary when nobody visits the site) you should go for a real Cronjob instead of `wp_cron`.

Comment: I have already second option, set corn job on server. I tried above custom recurrence `everysecond` but its not working though on local-host.

Comment: Yeah, that's what i expected - because on your localhost it will not often happen that you load your page every second ;)

Comment: Do you know the reason? Why?

Comment: As mentioned, `wp_cron` just executes IF the page is loaded. So if you set the interval to 1 second, and nothing happens on your site for 1 hour, `wp_cron` does not autmatically load itself. It is part of the WordPress script, and checks if it has to be executed whenever WordPress is loaded.

Comment: But am hitting website each & everysecond.

Comment: Install a Cron-Overview Plugin where you can see all your Crons. Set the scheduled time to 1 minute, just to see if everything works, and you should see the cron in your Overview list. Can you confirm that?

Comment: You such a rock star then. Am installing plugin and checking.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7678/discussion-between-fischi-and-frank)